# React needing 2 clicks on child component to change its state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a parent component, which is setting a state in a child component via props.

```
this.state = {
  addGroup: false,
}
buildGroupList = () => {
  const { addGroup } = this.state;
  return (
    <GroupListView onAdd={addGroup} />
  )
}
```

after triggered by a click it renders the child component

```
<TitleActionButton className="active" onClick={this.onAddGroupAction}>Add </...>

onAddGroupAction = () => {
   this.setState({ addGroup: !this.state.addGroup })
 }
```

my child component is receiving the props and setting it on the local state

```
componentWillReceiveProps(props) {
   this.setState({ isOnAddGroup: props.onAdd });
}

if (isOnAddGroup) return this.buildAddGroupView();
```

and at some point this state needs to be setted to false

```
onCancelAction = () => {
   this.setState({ isOnAddGroup: false, isOnEditGroup: false })
}
```

What I am not understanding is why I am having to click twice on the Trigger button (which is in the parent component) to change the state and consequently render my child component.

Any thoughts ?

Comment: We need more code. That `if (isOnAddGroup) return this.buildAddGroupView();` part looks suspicious. Is it placed inside `render()`?

Comment: @kinduser yes, it is. this function is not important at all, cuz its just logging few in stuff right now.

Comment: Okey, but anyways - is there a point to use `setState` at all? Why just not to use `props.onAdd` in every place where it's needed? Actually you don't need `componentWillReceiveProps` hook.

Comment: cuz in some point I will need to set the state to false, to hide the component, and I cant change props.

Comment: "_cuz in some point I will need to set the state to false_" - then do it, but keep the props. It'd look like `this.state.active && props.onAdd`